# MySQL JSON query with variables

Tags: mysql, json

How to use a MySQL variable within MySQL JSON select query. For example:

```
SET @rownum = 1;
select (`attributes`->'$.analyzeResult.documents[0].fields[0].Items.valueArray[@rownum].valueObject.ProductCode.valueString') from table;
```

It throws an error saying "syntax error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @rownum = 1;
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(attributes, CONCAT('$.analyzeResult.documents[0].fields[0].Items.valueArray[', @rownum, '].valueObject.ProductCode.valueString') 
FROM table;
```